# show updated data in bootstrap form modal without closing it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a form in bootstrap modal to add a meal, that would be stored in the database.This modal shows a list of already meals added and a field to add a new meal.I want that if I add a new meal, can I see the new meal added to the list before it refreshed up.
Thank you.

Comment: AJAX *(for storing the meal's details in the database)* plus JavaScript/jQuery *(for displaying the newly added meal without refreshing)*

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp